# having trouble with piping multiple times

Tags: bash, terminal

So, this program writes some stuff to a file and some stuff to the terminal

```
./program input.txt > output.txt
```

In addition to what it dumps to output.txt, it prints out some stuff to the screan. I tried to direct what it prints in the terminal but I failed:

```
./program input.txt > output.txt &>>log
```

But log ends up being empty.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`bash` doesn't let you redirect `stdout` twice. Instead, redirect stdout and stderr separately:

```
./program input.txt > output.txt 2> log
```